# Joining image - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

How do I merge two images with Delphi . I thought of using `CopyRect` but could not implement it. How do I attach a JPG image with the bitmap rectangle-shaped . I need to center the image within the rectangle , how?

[image]

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bmp, bmp1: TBitmap;
  jpg: TJpegImage;
  scale: Double;
begin

  if opendialog1.execute then
  begin
    jpg := TJpegImage.Create;
    try
      jpg.Loadfromfile(opendialog1.filename);
      if jpg.Height > jpg.Width then
        scale := 98 / jpg.Height
      else
        scale := 98 / jpg.Width;
      bmp := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        {Create thumbnail bitmap, keep pictures aspect ratio}
        bmp.Width := Round(jpg.Width * scale);
        bmp.Height:= Round(jpg.Height * scale);

        //BPM1
         bmp1 := TBitmap.Create;
         bmp1.SetSize(98, 98);
         bmp1.Canvas.Brush.Color := RGB(243,243,243);
         bmp1.Canvas.Pen.Style:= psClear;
         bmp1.Canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, 98, 98);

        bmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(bmp.Canvas.Cliprect, jpg);
        {Draw thumbnail as control}
        //Juntar os 2
        self.Canvas.Draw(10, 10, bmp1);
        self.Canvas.Draw(10, 10, bmp);
        Logo.Picture.Assign(bmp);
        {Convert back to JPEG and save to file}
        jpg.Assign(bmp);
        jpg.SaveToFile(
          ChangeFileext(opendialog1.filename, '_thumb.JPG')
        );
      finally
        bmp.free;
        bmp1.free;
      end;
    finally
      jpg.free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: could he helpful for effectively putting different sized images into imagelist as required for thumbbnails.

Answer (score 4):

You should not be using `bmp.Canvas.ClipRect` as the destination rectangle for your `StretchDraw()` call.  Specify the actual rectangle you want, which in this case is the full dimensions of `bmp`.

If you want a border *all the way around* the scaled image but keep the 98x98 dimensions of the final image, like your example JPG shows, then your scale needs to be based on a value less than 98px.  For instance, to have a border at least 10x wide, reduce your scale by 20px (10px on each side).  If you don't reduce your scale, the width and/or height of the scaled image will be exactly 98px, which is not what your example JPG shows.

When you go to draw `bmp` on top of `bmp1`, center `bmp` by subtracting its dimensions from `bmp1`'s dimensions and dividing the result in half.

And do not draw on the Form's `Canvas` from outside of the Form's `OnPaint` event.  If you want the Form to display an image, use the `TImage` component for that.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bmp, bmp1: TBitmap;
  jpg: TJPEGImage;
  scale: Double;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      jpg.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
      if jpg.Height > jpg.Width then
        scale := 78 / jpg.Height
      else
        scale := 78 / jpg.Width;

      bmp := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        {Create thumbnail bitmap, keep pictures aspect ratio}
        bmp.SetSize(Round(jpg.Width * scale), Round(jpg.Height * scale));
        bmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), jpg);

        //BPM1
        bmp1 := TBitmap.Create;
        try
          bmp1.SetSize(98, 98);
          bmp1.Canvas.Brush.Color := RGB(243, 243, 243);
          bmp1.Canvas.Pen.Style := psClear;
          bmp1.Canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height);

          bmp1.Canvas.Draw((bmp1.Width - bmp.Width) div 2, (bmp1.Height - bmp.Height) div 2, bmp);

          {Draw thumbnail as control}
          //Juntar os 2
          Image1.Picture.Assign(bmp1);
        finally
          bmp1.free;
        end;

        Logo.Picture.Assign(bmp);
        {Convert back to JPEG and save to file}
        jpg.Assign(bmp);
        jpg.SaveToFile(ChangeFileExt(OpenDialog1.FileName, '_thumb.JPG'));
      finally
        bmp.free;
      end;
    finally
      jpg.free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: In this code example, bmp is assigned using `jpb.Assign(bmp);`. not bmp1. Is this a mistake?

Comment: @sevenOfNine no, it is not a mistake. `bmp1` is the scaled image with border added, that is the image displayed in the UI. `bmp` is just the scaled image by itself, that is the image saved to file.

Comment: Now I understand the intention.Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I was stirring until I fulfilled what he wanted. The only thing I could not , was to change the image background , I would put in the empty spot RGB ( 0,0,0 ) , did the tests, but failed.

[image][image][image][image]
[image]

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
  jpg: TJPEGImage;
  scale: Double;
  widthL, HeightL, pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4: integer;
  verdd : boolean;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
  try
          jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
          verdd := false;
          try
            //Dimensões
            widthL := 98;
            HeightL := 98;
            jpg.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
            if (jpg.Height >= jpg.Width) AND (HeightL <= jpg.Height) then begin
              scale := widthL / jpg.Height;
            end else if (jpg.Height <= jpg.Width) AND (widthL <=  jpg.Width) then begin
              scale := HeightL / jpg.Width;
            end else begin
              verdd := true;
            end;
                bmp := TBitmap.Create;
                try
                  {Create thumbnail bitmap, keep pictures aspect ratio}
                  bmp.SetSize( widthL,HeightL);
                  if not verdd then begin
                      pt1 := (widthL - Round(jpg.Width * scale)) div 2;
                      pt2 := (HeightL - Round(jpg.Height * scale)) div 2;
                      pt3 := Round(jpg.Width * scale) + pt1;
                      pt4 := Round(jpg.Height * scale) + pt2;
                      bmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4), jpg);
                  end else begin
                      pt1 := (widthL - jpg.Width) div 2;
                      pt2 := (HeightL - jpg.Height) div 2;
                      pt3 := jpg.Width + pt1;
                      pt4 := jpg.Height + pt2;
                      bmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4), jpg);
                  end;

                  Logo.Picture.Assign(bmp);
                  {Convert back to JPEG and save to file}
                  jpg.Assign(bmp);
                  jpg.SaveToFile(ChangeFileExt(OpenDialog1.FileName, '_thumb.JPG'));
                finally
                  bmp.free;
                end;
          finally
            jpg.free;
          end;
  except
       showMessage('Erro ao carregar imagem');    ///////////////////////////////////
  end;
  end;
end;
```